# How can i use a Future Int using a Provider?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, provider

I am trying to show a live count of total documents in an Appbar. I get the right information in my console, but when i try to pass it with an Provider it returns an Instance of 'Future'. Can someone tell why i am getting still an Instence even if i await the result and the result is printed correctly in my console?

this is where i get the Future int and print the result to my console.

```
class AuthenticationService extends ChangeNotifier {


 Future<int> totalJumps(jumpDict) async {
    var respectsQuery = _db.collection(jumpDict);

    var querySnapshot = await respectsQuery.get();
    var result = querySnapshot.docs.length;
    print(result);
    // notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }
}
```

This is were it should show the result as a int in the title of the appBar

```
class LazyListOnline extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'Lazy_list_online';
  @override
  _LazyListOnlineState createState() => _LazyListOnlineState();
}

class _LazyListOnlineState extends State<LazyListOnline> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String userDict = Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context).findJumpDict;

    var _firestoreDb =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(userDict).snapshots();

    var totalJump = Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context)
        .totalJumps(userDict)
        .toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomeDrawer.id);
            }),
        title: Text('totalJumps'),
      body: Stack(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(),
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestoreDb,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return JumpItem(
                      snapshot: snapshot.data,
                      index: index,
                    );
                  });
            }),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're attributing a string to the totalJump var in the build method. You need to wait till the function is completed to get the value. Use FutureBuilder to get it, it's a good option.

Comment: Thank you mate! never used the Future builder! That was what i was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to store only the amount of documents as an int in Provider like.

```
 class DocumentData extends ChangeNotifier {
    int documentLength;

       void setCurrentLengthOfDocuments(int length) {
         this. documentLength = length;
         notifyListeners();
       }
 }
```

Then in StreamBuilder. Every time data has been changed. You just need to update. Regrading to your example be something like.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestoreDb,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

              // Update amount of documents length
              Provider.of<DocumentData>(context, listen: false)
                .setCurrentLengthOfDocuments(lengthOfCurrentDocuments);

              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return JumpItem(
                      snapshot: snapshot.data,
                      index: index,
                    );
                  });
            }),
      ]),
```

Then when you can get the length of documents every where on this page by just use Consumer widget. Or get the value directly from Provider.